# How to get current Test Case ID in the mtm for data driven test

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, coded-ui-tests, data-driven-tests

I use data driven test and coded ui test. I want to capture current Test Case ID that's current being run in the MTM. How can I do? For example;

```
[Datasource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.TestCase", "http://alm...", "?????",  DataAccessMethod.Sequential), TestMethod]

public void login1()
{
this.UIMAP.Login(TestContext.DataRow["url"].ToString());
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't**.

All attributes need constant values and you cannot pass something that its value will not be known at compile time.

So, you have to pre-define the value of the test case id when you code your test.